# Ubuntu with Secure Boot Enabled

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu.
I want to install Ubuntu with Secure Boot option enabled. If I enable secure boot option in BIOS, I cannot boot using the Ubuntu USB installation disk. I get the error - "Image authorization fail. System can not boot to this device due to security violation".
If I turn off Secure Boot in BIOS, everything works.
How can I install Ubuntu with Secure Boot enabled? The reason I want Secure Boot option enabled is because I am planning to install Windows 11 as VM guest using VirtualBox.
If Secure Boot is not enabled, I believe it won't let me install Windows.
Any help is appreciated.

This is the PC I built myself few years back.

Intel DZ87KLT-75K desktop board
32 GB RAM
Intel i7-4770K CPU at 3.5 GHz 8 core

I am not planning to Dual Boot. I just want Ubuntu as Host OS and Windows as VM Guest.

Thanks.

Comment: Installing in a VM is unrelated with the Secure Boot setting in the real machine. So, if that's the only problem it isn't a problem at all. If later you want to install a dual-boot then you have to enable Secure Boot and some vendors require setting trust even for installation media. ACER and a few others do. So, posting your hardware specification and make/model might help. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for your reply. I have added hardware specs. Windows 11 requires Secure Boot option enabled. When I tried to install Windows 11 AS VM on Ubuntu Host, I got Secure Boot related error. So in-spite of being VM, is it still looking for the BIOS settings of the host machine?

Comment: VM is NOT dual-boot. Dual-booting implies both OSes installed on bare metal. If you're getting such error in a VM then the settings of whatever virtualization software you're using than need to be changed. Again, nothing to do with the real machine UEFI settings and **this isn't a Ubuntu question**.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Got it. Thanks for the information. I posted the question here because I thought I needed to install Ubuntu with Secure Boot option and I did not know how to do that.